# Printing list with additional text

Tags: c#

Edit:
So currently I am creating a struct:

```
 struct Coordinate
{
    public string Name;
    public int HP;
    public int EXP;

    public Coordinate(string name, int hp, int exp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.HP = hp;
        this.EXP = exp;
    }
  }
}
```

I have also created this list:

```
var myList = new List<Coordinate>();
```

And this is a code i have been working on:

```
                        {Console.Write("name:");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();


                        Console.Write("hp:");
                        int hp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.Write("exp:");
                        int exp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Coordinate point = new Coordinate(name, hp, exp);
                        Console.WriteLine("Pokemon's name: "+point.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(point.HP); //output: hp inputed  
                        Console.WriteLine(point.EXP); //output: 20 
                        myList.Add(point);
 
                    }

                    else if (menu == '6'){ //need help here, want to print list
                    }
```

How to I add the list so that when I input 6, I want to write this:

```
Pokemon's name = Charmander
Pokemon's HP = 20
Pokemon's EXP = 40
```

Comment: It seems like you should be creating a `PokemonMaster`, not a `Dictionary`, and then adding it to `pokemans`

Comment: `if (myDictionary.Count <= 0)` will only add your new pokemon if there are none. It works the first time because there are none, but once you add the 1st one the code will no longer add any other new pokemons even though you read their info.

Comment: oh ignore the PokemonMaster, thats for a later part of the code im not putting in

Answer (score 0):

This is probably incorrect:

```
if (myDictionary.Count <= 0)
{
    myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's Name", name);
    myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's HP", hp.ToString());
    myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's EXP", exp.ToString());
    myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's Skill", name);
    Console.WriteLine("Pokemon has been added!");

}
```

First of all, it will only run the code if the dictionary is empty, so trying to add another pokemon will not do anything.

Secondly, it adds the pokemons properties as separate values in the dictionary. So if you remove the `Count <= 0` check it will fail since keys are constants and have already been added. Regular dictionaries can only have a single value for a specific key.

You probably want to do the following:

- Introduce a Pokemon-class with name, hp, exp and skill properties.
- Replace myDictionary with a regular list of pokemons.
- Remove the `Count <= 0` check

If you only want to allow a single pokemon with a specific name you can keep the dictionary and change it to `myDictionary[myPokemonName] = myPokemonObject`. This will add a new pokemon, or overwrite any existing pokemon with the same name.

Comment: But for hp and exp i need to give it an input value while name and skill are fixed when creating the class and im not sure how to do that

Comment: @user15930341 I'm not sure what you mean. You can just keep the hp and exp as local fields and create the object when you have entered all of the properties.